# URL GET using Basic Auth with Java Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets, httpurlconnection

I have a .jsp page which handles some basic html (text field, submit button a table to populate) and javascript. On click it calls my java Servlet class which handles the request and the response from and to the jsp respectfully. I also have a Java class to handle url connection to make a REST call using GET which should return a json string result. This is the scenario: User wishes to make a simple search by entering an ID value to populate the table using REST to connect to a url and get a json response.

I have separately tested the Java class to make a REST call made by URL connection with Basic Authentication to GET the data in json string and it works perfectly fine. (I have coded 4 different methods of doing this and all work fine and return the expected json).

I have separately tested the jsp page making a call to the servlet to populate "dummy" values in the table and the servlet response is fine and the table populates as expected.

THE PROBLEM:

When I tried to populate the table by the values obtained from the GET REST call, it hangs and I get no result. So I tried to investigate why and found out that for some crazy reason, the servlet doesn't like the line of code which sets the header with the basic authentication to get access to the URL. I tried commenting the basic auth 1 line code out (to debug, so now we have no authentication) but passing through some "dummy" hard coded data, and it populates the table.

I actually don't know why the servlet doesn't like it when I set the authentication. My guess is probably it is overwriting the servlet's response path and therefore lost the initial response location to the jsp? (i.e. where to send the json back to?)  Can anyone help me here? Anyone know whats happening? is my assumption of the problem correct? if so, how do I overcome this problem?

Javascript call to the servlet:

```
$("#myForm2").submit(function(e) {
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "servlet1", // the script where the form input is handled.
       data: $("#myForm2").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
       success: function(responseData){
            var dataObj = $.parseJSON(responseData)
            $('#myTable').append(>>add values to table here<<);
       });

e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
$("#myForm2")[0].reset(); // clear previous values entered
});
```

Servlet class, request made by jsp page and the servlet's response:

```
Rest getCallOnURL = new Rest(); // instance of my rest class

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                  HttpServletResponse response) 
                  throws ServletException,IOException {
    // create a dummy string "test" to hold the ID value passed in from javascript
    String testID = request.getParameter("ID");

    // Hard coded - only for testing purposes
    if (testID.equals("1")){
        //call my java class' method to connect to url and retrieve the json string
        getCallOnURL.connectToUrlAndMakeAGetRequest();
        valueToPopulateTable = getCallOnURL.testJsonString;
    }

    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    // using backslash to escape the quotes to make a valid json response
    out.print("{\"testRow\": \"valueToPopulateTable\"}");
    out.close();
}
```

My Java Class method to make URL call and Basic Authentication:

```
String testJsonString = "defaultValue";//testing purposes

//creates a valid encoded authentication string
private String basicAuth(String name, String pass){
    String authString = name + ":" + pass;
    byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
    String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
    return authStringEnc;    
}

private HttpURLConnection prepareGETConnection(final URL verifierURL)
throws IOException {                    
    final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) verifierURL.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //this is the line which authorizes access to the url via Basic Auth
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + basicAuth(name, password));

    return connection;
}

public void connectToUrlAndMakeAGetRequest(){
    try {
        String webPage = "URL HERE";// pass it a valid REST url with endpoints
        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        HttpURLConnection conn = prepareGETConnection(url);

        // get the url response json string
        InputStream getUrlresponse = conn.getInputStream(); 
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getUrlresponse));
        //get only the first line of the string - testing purposes only!
        testJsonString = rd.readLine();
        rd.close();
        conn.disconnect();

    } catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("IO exception: "+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you have provided here does not make it clear exactly what is supposed to be happening, but I assume: `javascript ajax --> servlet --> Java::Rest class --> servlet --> ajax response`.  However, all of the methods you are using are already attempting to handle headers in specific ways. Most likely, headers have already been sent and cannot be modified. Specify content-type in your ajax request, and the `accepts` header in your servlet, to `application/json`.

Comment: You stripped the class definition and wrappers from your code, making it very difficult to figure out exactly what is going on. Please try to clean this up a bit, and make it more clear.

Comment: @TonyChiboucas That is correct: `javascript ajax --> servlet --> Java::Rest class --> servlet --> ajax response` . class definition for the servlet: `public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {`  class definition for the Rest class: `public class Rest implements java.io.Serializable {` Regarding headers, I tried to load the Rest class with headers except the basic auth header and it succeeds to populate the table in jsp with dummy vaues. I also tried to use `addRequestProperty()` instead of `setRequestProperty()` to avoid overwriting the basic auth header, still no luck.

Comment: Apart from that, the java code on servlet and Rest class contains no more than some variables declared, at the moment the only 2 factors i stripped out are that I am hard coding in the username and password on the `basicAuth(String name, String pass)` method and a URL link that requires basic authentication. I am using `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;` for the encoding, everything else is standard Java.

Comment: Your description says that your javascript works, but this bit of code could not: ` $('#myTable').append(>>add values to table here<<);`
I still can't tell how your Rest class is being called by the javascript.
Use a debugging tool to check headers, contentType, server's accepts header.

Comment: Take some time and see if you can manage to shrink all of this into the smallest code possible, that replicates the behavior without any additional modification. Even better, make a fiddle for it at jsfiddles.net or via the java option at https://fiddles.io/

Comment: @TonyChiboucas The table is declared like this:

`<table id="myTable" border = "2">
        <tr> 
            <th>Example Row </th>
        </tr>`

The ajax populates like this:

`$('#myTable').append(
                    "<tr>" +
                        "<td>"+ dataObj.testRow +"</td>" +
                    "</tr>"
               ); `

I did say I have a table that gets appended with values as standard JS, I didn't think it was necessary to show this.

Comment: Java script does not call the Rest class. Javascript calls the servlet in which calls the Rest class via an instance of the class.check the code on the servlet: `Rest getCallOnURL = new Rest(); // instance of my rest class`

then inside the `doGet()` call : `getCallOnURL.connectToUrlAndMakeAGetRequest();
        valueToPopulateTable = getCallOnURL.testJsonString;`

 where `valueToPopulateTable` is a simple string variable called in a sloppy way but I am in no rush to create getters and setters for this untill I fix the bigger issue of why the servlet dislikes the basic auth header

Comment: As I mentioned... separately this code works perfectly fine. (i.e. if i try to run the Rest class, I get the full json response as expected, similarly if i try to run the servlet by populating hard coded dummy values, it works just fine and appends the table in JS, but when i try to GET some json from a url via RESful webservices and passing the value through, it doesnt seem to work. Logically it should, but there must be something preventing it.. like the response path back to the jsp is probably lost? or something with overwriting the headers? or something else?

Comment: Have you checked the headers being sent to the servlet?
Have you tried setting the ajax content-type to `application/json`?
Have you check that the servlet is set to accept that content-type?

Comment: It doesn't seem to like anything to do with making that GET request. I have literally exhausted every option. I am now forced to try this via a workaround solution, (e.g. make the rest on java script) i know it is very bad, but it is a starting point as a temporary step. Then I can work my way up from that and see where the limitations are. Unless you have a better idea?